# N+1 query in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue with a N+1 in my User model that I'm not sure how to fix. The method is setup like this:

```
 has_many :group_questions, through: :groups, source: :questions
 has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
 has_many :questions, through: :question_participants

  # Collection of Users questions
  def all_questions
    group     = group_questions
    personal  = questions
    all_questions = group + personal
  end
```

it gathers questions related to a group that a User is in, but also personal questions directed to that person. Finally it merges them into one array.

The N+1's I'm getting are:

```
N+1 Query detected
  User => [:group_questions]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:group_questions]

User => [:questions]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:questions]
```

happens on this line:

```
current_user.all_questions.any?
```

Comment: Where are you getting the user from the database?  In that query add the suggested includes.  `User.includes(:group_questions, :questions)`

Comment: updated with the view

Comment: I assume current user is a controller helper_method?  That's where you'd do the includes, but if you're only doing it on that view I'd consider doing a db query to include the group_questions and questions in the controller action for that action so you're not loading them everywhere.

Comment: Yes current_user is a helper method. As you said, I think the best answer is  to do what you suggested last, however I'm uncertain on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User 
  scope :with_questions, -> { includes(:questions, :group_questions) }

  def all_questions
    # No need for variables if you only use them once!
    group_questions + questions
  end
end
```

---

```
def show
  @user = User.with_questions.find(params[:id])
end
```

You could use `default_scope` but it's not really a good idea because it will slow down the cases where you don't need the joined records.

### Added

I just saw your comment about getting the user from `current_user`. Although loading everything in one query would be optimal overriding the user loading in the authentication logic is a mess for a marginal performance gain. Instead you can do it like this:

```
@user = User.eager_load(:questions, :group_questions)
            .find(current_user.id)
```

`eager_load` will force ActiveRecord to load the records upfront in a single query. Try playing around with `joins`, `includes` and `eager_load` in the rails console and check the difference in the the resulting SQL queries.

- http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading-revised?view=asciicast

Comment: I would also consider querying the other way around - query the Questions model and join the groups and users and use the user id as a condition. It makes more sense if what you want in the end is group of questions.

Comment: how would I accomplish doing this in the view with "current_user.all_questions.any? I tried adding @user = current_user.with_questions but got a no method error

Comment: `with_questions` is a scope. Scopes are called on model classes or ActiveRecord relation objects - not model instances. So you would do `@user = User.with_questions.find(current_user.id)`.

Comment: On a side note **do not query in your views**. That's how you get n+1 problems in the first place. Thats also why crap software like wordpress fires 50 queries per request. Do your queries upfront in your controller instead - your views should be as dumb and simple as possible.